# how to set x-auth-token in header angular 5

Tags: angular, token, httpclient

I am new to angular , I have a api to create session wherein response I am getting sessionId , so I am storing that in session storage :

```
sessionStorage.setItem('token',res["sId"]);
```

then after this I am calling another api where i want to set same token,so I am doing like this :

```
public opt={
  headers: new HttpHeaders().set('x-auth-token', JSON.stringify(sessionStorage.getItem('token')))
}
```

api call :

```
Initialcheck(reqpara){
  return this.http.post(this.check1_url,reqpara,this.opt )
}
```

But I am facing one problem , in api call it is taking previous token not the current one.Please help me out.

Comment: it seems that the `sessionStorage.setItem()` is called after that request. Therefore the request reads the old value. Could that be the case?

Comment: I am calling getsession() on ngOnInit() and after that there is one button in html , on clicking that I am sending sessionId

Answer (score 2):

Probably because the instance of HttpHeader is immutable you can't set properly the headers. Try to do it in this way:

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers = headers.set('x-auth-token',JSON.stringify(sessionStorage.getItem('token'));
opt.headers = headers;
```

or

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders({'x-auth-token':JSON.stringify(sessionStorage.getItem('token')});
opt.headers = headers;
```